# Nginx request map and redirect have no effect

Tags: redirects, url-rewriting, nginx

I want to rewrite/return request to new one

I have:

- map

  ```
  map $request $new_request {
      include url_rmap.conf;
  }
  ```
- file url_rmap.conf

  ```
  # here i have tried  all variations
  $scheme://d.dom https://any.other/address
  $scheme://d.dom/ https://any.other/address
  https://d.dom https://any.other/address
  https://d.dom/ https://any.other/address
  ```
- server block

  ```
  server {

       listen ip:port;
       server_name a.dom b.dom aa.a.dom w.c.dom d.dom;

       # first try 
       if($new_request) {
             return 301 $new_request;
       }

       # also second with @redirect-nap
       location / {
          # Support Clean (aka Search Engine Friendly) URLs
          try_files  @redirect-map $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args; 
       }

       location @redirect-map {
            if ($new_request) {  # redirect if the variable is defined
                  return 301 $new_request;
            }
       }

  }
  ```

both ways with to call `https://d.dom` fail to redirect and have no effect. why?